# Why is this erlang tftpd server seemingly not accepting client requests?

Tags: erlang, tftp

I'm attempting to use inet's tftp, but I'm doing something incorrectly. [This
simple example application](https://github.com/blt/tftp-problems), while it does bind to the correct port, never
returns data to a client.

To reproduce, open a terminal in the project root and:

```
make && ./bin/console
```

This should boot the tftp_hellp application, and drop you into an erlang
shell. Confirm that inets is running:

```
1> application:which_applications().
[{inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","5.9"},
 {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.2.1"},
 {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.18.1"},
 {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.15.1"}]
```

and that the tftp daemon is running:

```
2> inets:services().
[{tftpd,<0.56.0>},{httpc,<0.50.0>}]
```

Great. Now, if you look in `etc/inets.config` you'll notice we're binding tftpd
to 6969. Open another terminal and:

```
> tftp localhost 6969
tftp> get hello.txt
Transfer timed out.
```

Bother. If my understanding of tftpd were correct--which clearly it's not--we'd
get `<<"hello world">>` back.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially received the same error, but then checked my firewall settings to allow udp/6969 and got the file:

`-> % tftp localhost 6969`

tftp> get hello.txt

Received 11 bytes in 0.0 seconds

tftp> quit

-> % cat hello.txt

hello world%